# What is this weird dynamic method dispatch behavior inside a static method in Java

Tags: java, dynamic-dispatch

The utility method in the below example is for illustration purposes only.

In the example below, `instance method` invocation was dispatched to reference type but not to the run-time object.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
public class DynamicMethodDispatchEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timestamp now = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Timestamp beforeNow = new Timestamp(now.getTime() - 1);

        System.out.println("Finding newest in " + now + " and " + beforeNow);
        System.out.println("Attempt 1: " + staticFindNewer(beforeNow, now));
        System.out.println("Attempt 2: " + staticFindNewer(now, beforeNow));

    }

    public static Date staticFindNewer(Date one, Date two) {
        if (one.after(two)) {
            return one;
        } else {
            return two;
        }
    }

}
```

The below was the output I got

```
Finding newest in 2016-08-23 17:56:36.375 and 2016-08-23 17:56:36.374
Attempt 1: 2016-08-23 17:56:36.375
Attempt 2: 2016-08-23 17:56:36.374 // <---
```

After some investigation, I found out that `java.util.Date.after(Date)` was being invoked in the `staticFindNewer()` and the discrepancy in attempt 1 and 2 and was due to precision loss as Date's methods were being used.

However, I'm puzzled about dynamic dispatch. *I expected `Timestamp#after(Timestamp)` to be invoked but `Date#after(Date)` was getting invoked.* I thought the instance-method dispatch was always based on runtime object. Am I missing something silly (most probably)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you confused about? Assuming you're referring to `java.sql.Timestamp`, that's a subtype of `java.util.Date`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was expecting `one.after(two)` to be dispatched to java.sql.Timestamp but it was dispatched to `java.util.Date`

Comment: You mean you expected `Timestamp#after(Timestamp)` to be invoked instead of `Date#after(Date)`? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Both objects are `Timestamp` objects - But the argument type to the method is determined at compile time. In this case, your static method takes in a `Date` so it uses that.

Comment: Wow, nice find @SotiriosDelimanolis.

Comment: @shmosel "Timestamp after overload". I've been around long enough to remember some of these more exotic posts.

Comment: Some more discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929242/compare-date-object-with-a-timestamp-in-java  I suppose the lesson is to avoid the old date/time API and go with `java.time` as much as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected `Timestamp#after(Timestamp)` to be invoked but `Date#after(Date)` was getting invoked. I thought the instance-method dispatch was always based on runtime object.

Dynamic dispatch happens only on the invoked object, not on the arguments.

So the call would go to `Timestamp#after(Date)` (because the compile-time type of the argument is `Date`, and the runtime type of the callee is `Timestamp`).

Unfortunately, `Timestamp` does not override this method, so it defaults back to `Date#after(Date)` (which does not work too well here).

So you have to make sure you call `Timestamp#after(Timestamp)` directly, or use the `Date#compareTo(Date)` method instead, which is properly implemented (and overridden in `Timestamp`).

Comment: Thanks. This sheds light on the issue. But there's no `java.sql.Timestamp#after(Date date)`.

Comment: I thought it was there. I confused it with `Timestamp#compareTo(Date)` (which is properly implemented). Wonder why `after` is not just dispatching to `compareTo`...